# Iterate a IDictionary/Dictionary Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, loops

I have code where this is declared:

```
 public IDictionary<string, OPTIONS> dict_Options = new Dictionary<string, OPTIONS>();

 public class OPTIONS
 {
        public string subjectId = string.Empty;
        public string varNumber = string.Empty;
        public string varName = string.Empty;
 }
```

What's the easiest way to iterate over all the varNames in my dictionary object? Is there like a foreach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        foreach (var item in dict_Options)
        {
            string varName = item.Value.varName;
        }
```

This iterates through all the `KeyValuePair<T, T>` in your dictionary

Answer (score 4):

Just to add an alternative to the great answers already posted, you could do:

```
dict_Options.Keys.ToList().ForEach(m => SomeFunc(m.Value.varName));
```

Comment: ...How could `m.Value` return something if `m` is actually the Key? I would write `dict_Options.Keys.ToList().ForEach(m => SomeFunc(dict_Options[m]));`

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var name in dict_Options.Select(x => x.Value.varName))
{
    SomeFunc(name);
}
```